# Converting PHP MySQL date to Javascript timestamp for FLOT time series data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, flot

I am currently working on creating a Flot JavaScript Time Series Line Graph. The graph analyses the number of users who create an account with against the time that the account was created.

Here is a screenshot of the users table
[image: database]

I have so far been able to retrieve the created_date column in the users table x asis used for the graph. The y axis is then calculated using the **COUNT()** function in a separate query. My codes are found below.

PHP:

```
<?php

include "connection/connect2.php"; 
$datecreated = "SELECT created_date FROM users";
$rundatecreated = mysql_query($datecreated);
$foundnum = mysql_num_rows($rundatecreated);
while ($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($rundatecreated)) {
$dataset1[] = $runrows['created_date'];
}

if (is_array($dataset1)){
foreach($dataset1 as $x) {

  $query = mysql_query("SELECT created_date, count(created_date) as date FROM users WHERE created_date='$x' "); 
  while ($runquery = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
       $y[]= $runquery['created_date'] .",".$runquery['date']."<br>" ;
      } 
}

$graph=implode(" ", $y);
echo $graph;

} else {

echo "error";
}

?>
```

I then store the data retrieved using these two queries into an array, as shown below.

[image: results]

I am unsure of how to convert the date data currently retrieved using my PHP codes into JavaScript timestamp format. Is there any way I can do so using PHP codes?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `JavaScript timestamp format`? Do you have an example of how you want it to read?

Comment: @jun Jie do you want timestamp of output dates ? also your are getting duplicate records, is it necessory ?

Comment: @Darren Sweeney The format should be something like **[-373597200000, 315.71].** Here is the [link](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/axes-time/) to the official website for FLOT charts. Hope it helps!

Comment: @Noman Hi Noman, i'm unsure of what you mean by "timestamp of output dates". However, I do not require duplicate records and am unsure of how to remove them. Could you assist me on this matter? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1) You need only one SQL query to achieve this instead of one plus 1 per date. for this use grouping in the query.

2) To get timestamps from your dat values use the `getTimestamp()` method and multiply by 100 to convert from UNIX timestamps to JavaScript timestamps.

3) Flot need the data for a data series as array of array (data points). This can then be encoded as JSON and printed inside the JavaScript or fetched by AJAX.

Updated code (not tested but should be a good starting point):

```
<?php

include "connection/connect2.php";
$query = mysql_query("SELECT created_date, count(*) as date FROM users GROUP BY created_date "); 
$foundnum = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query));
while ($runquery = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $graph[] = array((new DateTime($runquery['created_date']))->getTimestamp() * 1000 , $runquery['date']);
} 

if ($foundnum > 0) {
   echo json_encode($graph);
} else {
    echo "error";
}

?>
```

Comment: Hi i tried out your codes, and am getting an error message. I'm getting  Fatal error: Call to a member function getTimestamp() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\php\flotdata.php on line 9. Can you help me with this? Thanks!